# Swagger project edit doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have a strange situation where I've been developing an app on my windows machine but when I run the same command for starting swagger on my Mac, it doesn't do anything.

When I run `swagger project edit`, it simply executes the script and there doesn't seem to be any errors or executions of any sort.

Thoughts?

Comment: what module did you install? what node version and npm versions are you using?

Comment: `Node v7.5.0`, `express ^4.12.3`, `swagger-express-mw ^0.1.0`

Comment: did you instal swagger-cli globally?

Comment: Yes, I have: `/Users/OSX/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin/swagger -> /Users/OSX/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib/node_modules/swagger-cli/bin/swagger.js
/Users/OSX/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib
└── swagger-cli@1.0.0-beta.2 
`

Comment: so if inside your terminal you go to where your project is and you type the command nothing happens? no message, nothing?

Comment: That's exactly right, @DayanMorenoLeon.  On my windows machine, it works but on my Mac, nothing at all. I'm not sure if there are other configurations I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall the `swagger-cli` tool and ensure I had both `swagger-cli` and `swagger` installed globally.